# How to achieve a generic Record field?

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

It would be fantastic to be able to do something like this:

```
class MyRecord<T> extends Immutable.Record<{
  field: T;
}>({}) {}
```

...but due to the API of `Immutable.Record`, you have to provide initial values.

Providing an initial value for a generic doesn't make sense and yet "Immutable.js" requires it.

Is there a way to achieve that sample (yet currently uncompilable) code?

P.S. I know that `field` could be made optional, but that would be an undesirable workaround in this case (plus I don't think "Immutable.js" would play nice with it when it comes to setting the value later on, anyway).